# InternalsVisibleTo and class inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, mstest, internalsvisibleto

I'm using `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to make some internal classes visible to the unit test suite.

While it's allowing me to create instances of internal classes, I cannot create a class that inherits from an internal class.

Is this behaviour expected? If it is, there's some other way to achieve what I want?

Edit: As pointed by @Grant Thomas, I did not say what I want. What I want is to create an instance of an abstract internal class. It's not that class I'm testing, but the class I'm testing have it as a dependency.

Comment: You haven't really said what it is that you _do_ want, just a _means_.

Comment: You shouldn't heed to inherit a class in order to test it.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, the class I want to inherit from is not the class I want to test, it's a dependency.

Comment: which assembly houses the inherited type?  What is the visibility of that class?  It might help to give us a quick gist code snapshots.